# Is there a way to have not formatted text block in Asciidoc?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

**Does it exist in Asciidoc (rendered by Asciidoctor) a way to have a block of text where asciidoc formatting is not applied, but it keeps the asciidoc paragraph format (background color, font, font color, etc...) and not preformated format ?**

### My specific problem

I have a paragraph that I want to render "as I type it"

```
Array(Element1, Element2, Element3)
```

Currently, it renders as follow:

[image: actual output]

And I want to render it as follow:

[image: Expected Output]

### What I've tried so far

I tried to use code block or literal block, but text appears as preformated, which I don't want:

```
----
Array(
  Element1,
  Element2,
  Element3
)
----
```

Or

```
[literal]
....
Array(
  Element1,
  Element2,
  Element3
)
....
```

Gives me the following output:

[image: attempts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get what I want by using [`[%hardbreaks]` option](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-writers-guide/#wrapped-text-and-hard-line-breaks) to keeping line breaks and by using [`{nbsp}` built-in attribute](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/character-replacement-ref/) for non-breaking spaces.

Here is the complete code:

```
[%hardbreaks]
Array(
{nbsp}{nbsp}Element1,
{nbsp}{nbsp}Element2,
{nbsp}{nbsp}Element3
)
```